# Can't address with currently assumed segment registers - ASM

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

I'm having a problem with a function that creates a file in ASM. When I compile it I get the error `Can't address with currently assumed segment registers`, and I don't know what can I do to fix it. Here's my code:

```
data segment
    option db 0
    nameF db "file.txt"
    create db 'C'
    handle dw ?
    rotuloIns db "Select instruction (C to create file): ", '$'
data endS

pila segment stack 'stack'
    dw 256 dup(?)
pila endS

code segment
createFile proc
    mov ah, 3Ch
    lea dx, nameF
    xor cx, cx
    int 21h
    mov handle, ax
    ret
createFile endP

main:
assume  cs:code, ds:data, ss:pila

    mov ax, ds
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, pila
    mov ss, ax
    mov si, 80h
    mov cl, byte ptr es:[si]
    xor ch, ch      
    xor di, di
    inc si
    dec cx

mov ah, 01H
    int 21H
    mov option, ah

mov bl, create
    cmp bl, option
    call createFile

code endS
end main
```

Any advice on how to fix it? I'm not really familiar with how registers work.

Comment: `option` is a reserved word in MASM/TASM. I'd avoid using a label of that name and use something else. The error about the segment is likely because in the function `createFile` there is no assumed segment for DS. Maybe inside `createFile` put a `assume  ds:data` or move `assume  cs:code, ds:data, ss:pila` before `createFile proc` `?

Comment: Is this MASM or TASM?  This error message is specific to the assembler directives, not just the instructions, so a [masm] or [tasm] tag would be appropriate for future readers to be able to find it later.

Comment: As for why I single out DS as the culprit is because the `mov ax, handle` instruction is the equivalent of ds:[handle] (the DS is implicit) but there is no assumed directive to say which segment should be assumed to have `handle`. I'm also tagging this `[tasm]` as the wording of the error seems to be specific to Borland's product.

Comment: NameF needs a null terminator for function 3C